# Socket messaging being received but weird characters being appended?

Tags: c#

So I'm writing an application which can schedule remote backups, I have received the message from the client, but the server is receiving unexpected characters at the end?

Client sends: `execute_task,name=PerformBackup`

Server receives: `execute_task,name=PerformBackup\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...`

Client code:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    using (Socket socket = client.Client)
    {
        await socket.ConnectAsync(endpoint);
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("execute_task,name=PerformBackup");
        socket.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
_buffer = new byte[1024]
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
_socket.Listen(0);
_socket.BeginAccept(OnConnection, _socket);

private void OnConnection(IAsyncResult iAr)
{
    var socket = ((Socket)iAr.AsyncState)?.EndAccept(iAr);
    socket?.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnMessage, socket);
    _socket.BeginAccept(OnConnection, _socket);
}

private async void OnMessage(IAsyncResult iAr)
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_buffer); // IE the message, with '\0\0...' appended
}
```

Comment: Try searching, this question literally gets asked every day. You're ignoring the number of bytes received. You're also missing an application ("framing") protocol: the client has no idea how long the incoming message is, or how to discern between two messages received in rapid succession. Do. Not. Roll. Your. Own. Socket. Protocol. Use something like HTTP+JSON, or pick any other existing application protocol for which clients and servers already widely exist. If you're doing this to learn things, find a proper book.

Comment: Also, don't use `BeginReceive` (for which you have no matching `EndReceive` call in `OnMessage` to *get* the number of bytes received, for what it's worth). Use `*Async` methods with async/await instead.

Comment: When working with sockets you have *no* idea how many bytes are in a message. Perhaps the server is sending bytes one by one. Perhaps it stalled for a while. Perhaps it's sending a large text little by little. *The developer* (ie you) has to define how to identify a message - that's what framing is about. Do you have fixed length messages? Messages that end with a specific byte sequence? Do you specify the length of the message in the first few bytes? It's up to you to specify that protocol and implement it

Comment: BTW this means that you *will* get multiple messages in the same buffer after a while, or receive only part of a message because the buffer is full. It's up to *you* to handle all this. Instead of rolling your own it would be better to use an existing protocol like, eg gRPC or HTTP

Comment: Thanks! I've read all your comments and taken a lot of information from them. I'll look into framing, and using asynchronous methods.

Comment: @myzddwnuxwzpjndeyl why?????? Why not use gRCP instead? Or any other protocol? At least gRCP is *very* fast and allows you to use existing libraries. It also allows you to design the messages and leave the details to the libraries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is something I've already tried gRCP, REST APIs, I'm just looking into lower level concepts to broaden my knowledge, and enjoy my hobby. King regards.

Comment: @myzddwnuxwzpjndeyl *this is something I've already tried* - did you succeed? why not stick with it? When you've mastered this, will you bust out an assembler? Have a go at analyzing ethernet packets using an oscilloscope? At some point it just plain up makes sense to stop digging to ever lower levels, because you get less and less done each time, and just use a really good wheel that somebody already invented. If you set out to make a coffee by growing beans it's going to take a really long time, and at the end of it you'll have learnt not a considerable amount more than you knew before

Answer (score 2):

Some alarmbells here:

Sending: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("execute_task,name=PerformBackup");`

Receiving: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_buffer);`.

Check your encoding..

---

Also you should check the bytesReceived and use it in the GetString overload: `public string GetString (byte* bytes, int byteCount);`

```
private async void OnMessage(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    Socket server_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

    // check how many bytes we actually received
    var numBytesReceived = server_conn.EndReceive(iar);

    var myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_buffer, numBytesReceived);
```

And even then you'll face half packets etc...

If you want "plain" sockets, it's a lot to deal with.

I advise you to work with something like websockets.

Answer (score 0):

When working with sockets you either need a termination character or you need a header specifying how many bytes you are sending. I usually send the first 4 bytes as a "header" which converts to the size of the buffer that you are sending and then I receive 4 bytes and then I initialise a array to receive. Here is code sample with which you can work with

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    using (Socket socket = client.Client)
    {
        await socket.ConnectAsync(endpoint);
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("execute_task,name=PerformBackup");

        byte[] data_length = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
        socket.Send(data_length, data_length.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        socket.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
}
```

Then I have this method to do the receiving

```
    byte[] ReadBytes(Socket client, int size)
    {
        var data = new byte[size];
        var t = 0;
        do
        {
            var r = client.Receive(data, t, size - t, SocketFlags.None);
            if (r == 0)
            {
                throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.ConnectionReset);
            }
            t += r;
        } while (t != size);
        return data;
    }
```

and I use it like this:

```
var sizeBuffer = ReadBytes(socket,4);
var data = ReadBytes(socket, BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeBuffer , 0));
var stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data); // This willl then be what you are looking for
```

Comment: If you want to use BeginReceive etc I can convert the above code for you aswell